# Razor manipulate url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I am using asp.net mvc to build a page where i have to show alot of users in a table. I would like to make a paged view with an url like: 
mypage.com/Customer/{pageno}/{sorttype}/{somethingelse}

The urls would be located different places on a page. E.g. the "next page" button would have the same url, with just {pageno} increased, and the table headers would have {sorttype} different.

Is there a nice way to do this in razor, or will i just have to get the raw url, and parse it myself?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave URL generation to ASP.NET MVC routing. In the global.asax you should configure route for your Customer page correctly so it can take pageno, sorttype and somethingelse parameters.

Then in Razor you should simply use Url.Action (or Html.ActionLink) method, so the URL would be generated for you. You can use following overload in your case:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197(v=vs.118).aspx

If you find it too complex to write stuff like @Url.Action("Index", "Customer", new { pageno = 1, sorttype = "type", somethingelse = "test"), then you can add another extension method like Url.MyAction which will take 3 parameters (int pageno, string sorttype, string somethingelse) and call Url.Action internally. However I wouldn't suggest doing that because the readability of your code will surprisingly decrease. Everybody know Url.Action method, while your new Url.MyAction would be something new to other developers reading your code.

Again, the key is correct routing, so Url.Action() will be rendered to "/Customer/1/type/test". You can find more information on the link below: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Go it working using @Url.RouteUrl since it would allow me to get the 1/something/23 format by giving it a parameter that pointed to one of my specified routeconfigs. Thanks.